# Binding signal to property's slot in designer

Tags: qt, properties, designer, signals-slots

Is there a way to bind some signal not to wigget slot, but to widget's property slot in designer?
I do can connect stuff in widget's ctor or add some custom slots to my widget to proxy slot invokation, but it I do not want to make my widget know about what should be connected where or overload my widget with a number of such "dumb" slots.
It would be great to declare, say qt's property, and have possibility to bind signal to it's slot directly in designer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed create connections in Designer. Just use the Signal/Slot editor in designer and select a widget in your form as the sender, select the signal, select the receiving object and the slot you want called.